# Assigning image from photo album to a variable Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting image from a photo album with this code:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];}
```

Please Could anyone help me to assign this image to a variable? I want to blur it later using [stackblur](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS):

```
UIImage *newIma=[oldIma stackBlur:radius];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `UIImage` when you're getting the image that the user has selected.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // Create the UIImage in your @implementation and set it here
    myImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    myImageView.image = myImage;
}
```